# Wrap a span around all children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the contents of a div and wrap a span around it and append back to the div.

From this:

```
<div>
<a href="#">12</a>
Testing
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div>
<span>
<a href="#">Hehhehe</a>
Testing
</span>
</div>
```

So I tried this:

```
var span = $(document.createElement('span'));

var contents = window.jQuery(this).children();

span.append(contents);

window.jQuery(this).append(span); // I am looping here but this is the div
```

However, the text "Testing" is always outside the span!

How can I get everything to be within the span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.children()` doesn't include text nodes. Use `.wrapInner` to add the span around your elements.

Comment: Thanks Rob, didn't know that function exists!

Answer (score 5):

This should do what you want..

```
$('div').wrapInner('<span>');
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/76ND5/

---

If in your code `this` refers to the div in question, then all you need is

```
$(this).wrapInner('<span>');
```