# Target text within <a> and wrap it in a span

Tags: jquery

How can I target the text within an `<a>` and wrap it in a span?

So original code is:

```
<a href="#"><span class="accordionToggleCross"><img src="toggle.svg" title="Read more" alt="Read more"></span>
Job title #01
<span class="jobDescriptionSpan">Hello</span>
</a>
```

What I want it to become is:

```
<a href="#"><span class="accordionToggleCross"><img src="toggle.svg" title="Read more" alt="Read more"></span>
<span class="jobTitleSpan">Job title #01</span>
<span class="jobDescriptionSpan">Hello</span>
</a>
```

Who can I target the text and add span tags around it? Cant seem to target the text of the

Comment: have you tried the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545003/wrap-a-span-around-all-children?rq=1

Comment: Thanks - didnt know `wrapInner` existed. How can I get it to not nest all the contents in a span though - just want the text of the link targetted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.contents()` which returns all the child nodes of the element, including text nodes.

```
$('a').contents()
```

Then we iterate, check the text node, grab the text and replace it with the HTML.

```
if (this.nodeType == 3) {
    var u = this.nodeValue;
    $(this).replaceWith('<span class="jobTitleSpan">' + u + '</span>');
}`
```

Note:

1. It works if only you keep the structure of the HTML as-is. changing HTML will break this code

---

Working Example below

```js
$('a').contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 3) {
    var u = this.nodeValue;
    $(this).replaceWith('<span class="jobTitleSpan">' + u + '</span>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><span class="accordionToggleCross"><img src="toggle.svg" title="Read more" alt="Read more"></span>
Job title #01
<span class="jobDescriptionSpan">Hello</span>
</a> What I want it to become is:
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Markup wont change so this works well. Thank you

Comment: I should also add that if you can add an Id or a class to tjis anchor tag and then use the code with that id, will be more robust. Else if you run this code on the page with multiple anchors, it may produce unexpected results. Just FYI

Comment: For readability's sake you can change `3` to `Node.TEXT_NODE` (which holds the value `3`).